# Android Studio(last version) - Linking Failed

Tags: android, android-studio

Has anyone ever appeared to you this kind of problem ?
The program was running so far just made a change and gave me this error.
I creat a new project but cant build and appeared the same error .

[image: 1]

I wonder how can I solve this error.

Comment: Have you tried with clean/rebuild project or invalidate cache and restart?

Comment: Yes I tried but to no success.